# Start and get output of a .jar (E.g. Minecraft Bukkit .jar)

Tags: java, jar, bukkit

I'm trying to start some .jar inside an .jar using this code: (I'm trying with craftbukkit server right know)

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = rt.exec("java -jar craft.jar");
BufferedReader out = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
BufferedWriter in = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));
this.running = true;

while(this.running){
String line;
    if((line = out.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

The problem is, it work for a moment, but after a while it stops outputting or just print '>' as show in the image below. How can I fix this? **Plus, Which is the correct way to send commands to the bukkit server?

[image: An img of the error]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When using a `Process` in Java, it is crucial to read stdout and stderr in two independend threads (your while loop). Otherwise the child process can lock up waiting for the filled buffer to be drained.

With Java 7 you can actually redirect stderr to stdout, and possibly redirect the resulting stream to the parents stdout. With older versions you need to attach the seperate threads.

Besides: you should not use the "single string" variant of exec, but specify the args as arrays. This is safer (less vulnerable to parsing problems).

(But I am not sure if this is your actual problem. Maybe you should dump the error stream and see if it helps)

Answer (score 0):

I do it like that:

```
@Override
public void run(){
// ...
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream())); //of course proc is an instance of Process, and it's set up
while(true){
     String line = stdInput.readLine();
     if(line == null) break; //this is essential, when process terminates, line gets null
     System.out.println(">"+line);
    }
// ...
}
```

Give it a try.
(Technically it's similiar how you did, but it works for me so i share it)